# how to import code style to android studio in windows 10

Tags: android, android-studio, import, coding-style, settings

I have created my own code style @ home and want to use it for all projects in office PC. but i can just open `CodeStyleSettings` from `.idea` folder of my project and replace the code style. I exported my code style with **Manage** button in code style and export as xml.

I want to change or import Android studio code style. I googled but can not find a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Export at home:
File > Export Settings > Select which settings you want to export

Import anywhere else:
File > Import Settings > Browse to the exported file

Comment: I also tried this. but it have error with message: there is no setting to import.

Comment: Do you have a settings.jar?

Comment: I created this setting from code style manage button that creates a xml file for me.

Comment: Try it the way I suggested

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a code style you want to import the accepted solution doesn't really help you. Steps to add an existing XML profile (Windows):

1) Open C:\users[you].AndroidStudio[2.3]\config

2) If it doesn't already exist, create a directory "codestyles"

3) Restart Android Studio

4) Open File->Settings->Editor->Code Style. The new profile will appear in the list.